# Crystal reports with visual studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have installed crystal reports developer version SP5 - 64 bit from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074

Now, I am able to run my exes which has crystal reports references to them, however, when I open existing projects in visual studio, I am unable to get the report designer view of the .rpt files.

Same goes with a new project, I don't see any Crystal report templates under the Report tab when I try to add a new item.

Is there something else I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on my system, with only VS2012 and "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio SP5" installed. No additional software needed here...

Visual Studio IDE integration also works fine (i can open a .rpt file, and edit the report inside Visual Studio).